# Cursor speed in RXVT or URXVT

Tags: linux, cursor, urxvt, text-cursor

I am using RXVT (URXVT to be precise) under Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed that the cursor speed is extremely slow. I was looking to see if there is a setting that can be applied to speed cursor movement ?

Thanks for your attention.

RRS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
xset r rate 400 44
```

The delay (400) is the number of milliseconds before autorepeat starts.

The rate (44) is the number of repeats per second.

See `man xset` for details and lots of other options.

To see the current values before changing them:

```
xset q | grep rate
```

Comment: Is this like a one time thing I do, or I set this up in my `.bashrc` script. Or do I run `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults` ?

Comment: It is a temporary change, that you can run on the command line, and should take effect immediately. If it works, you'd need to include it in an X startup file (to be run when you login), but I'm not sure what file would be appropriate for Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have gnome-settings-daemon running, you will notice that the settings are overridden. You can modify the gnome settings with these commands: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard delay 400` and `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 22` (for reasons unknown to me you must halve the repeat-interval to get the same results as for `xset`)